# Finding shortest geospatial distance in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to find the shortest distance between the places and the user's location and I have two table namely: `Users_Location` and `Places`

**User's Table:**

```
|------------|------------|------------|
|   user_id  |  latitude  | longitude  |
|------------|------------|------------|
|    1       |  21.89027  | -53.03772  |
|    2       |  23.87847  | -41.78172  |
|    3       |  39.62847  | -80.19892  |
|    4       |  77.87092  | -96.39242  |
|    5       |  17.74962  | -28.56972  |
|------------|------------|------------|
```

**Places Table**

```
|--------------|------------|------------|
|    Places    |  latitude  | longitude  |
|--------------|------------|------------|
|  New York    |  72.92629  | -12.89272  |
|  Chicago     |  93.62789  | -83.10172  |
|  Dallas      |  68.92612  | -67.17242  |
|  Cincinnati  |  41.62729  | -37.19067  |
|  Milwaukee   |  86.90617  | -22.82997  |
|  Philadelphia|  38.91682  | -93.90692  |
|--------------|------------|------------|
```

I want to find the shorted distance between user's latitude-longitude to all other places.

The final table would look like:

```
|------------|-----------------|
|   user_id  |  nearest_place  |
|------------|-----------------|
|    1       |    New York     |
|    2       |    Milwaukee    |
|    3       |    Chicago      |
|    4       |    New York     |
|    5       |    Philadelphia |
|------------|-----------------|
```

I'm using Snowflake as a data-warehouse and tried to use the [HAVERSINE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/haversine.html) function to calculate the geospatial distance. But I don't get how do I loop over each place in `Places` table to get the shortest distance using SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should out put the closest city to user:

```
SELECT u.user_id, p.Places as nearest_place, 
    haversine( u.latitude, u.longitude, p.latitude, p.longitude) as distance
    FROM  users u, places p
    qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id order by distance) = 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Where Clause in the above query?

Comment: Yes we can use where clause before qualify and after from clause